# How to pipe a file into keen.io

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, keen-io

I have this program:

```
var planetStream = require('../../');
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(8000);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

var diffs = planetStream();

var buildings = diffs
.map(JSON.parse)
.filter(function (x) {
  return x.action === 'create' && x.type === 'way' &&
    x.tags.building;
});

buildings.onValue(function (x) {
  console.log(x);
  io.emit('buildings', x);
});
```

For data monitoring, I need to pipe it in keen.io. Does somebody know how to do this or did it before?

With Regards

Andrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found the answer.
To pipe the date into keen.io we need to implement all Code in HTML file. in my case it was index.html.

first we need to put this code before `</head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  !function(a,b){a("Keen","https://d26b395fwzu5fz.cloudfront.net/3.4.0-rc/keen.min.js",b)}(function(a,b,c){var d,e,f;c["_"+a]={},c[a]=function(b){c["_"+a].clients=c["_"+a].clients||{},c["_"+a].clients[b.projectId]=this,this._config=b},c[a].ready=function(b){c["_"+a].ready=c["_"+a].ready||[],c["_"+a].ready.push(b)},d=["addEvent","setGlobalProperties","trackExternalLink","on"];for(var g=0;g<d.length;g++){var h=d[g],i=function(a){return function(){return this["_"+a]=this["_"+a]||[],this["_"+a].push(arguments),this}};c[a].prototype[h]=i(h)}e=document.createElement("script"),e.async=!0,e.src=b,f=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],f.parentNode.insertBefore(e,f)},this);
</script>
```

than we need to implement in the `<body></body>` this code:

```
var client = new Keen({
  projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
  writeKey: "YOUR_WRITE_KEY"
});
```

project_ID and Your_Write_key you can find in keen.io after starting a new project.
The last step is too implement this function:

```
client.addEvent("osm_20_01", { key: data.nodes });
```

osm_20_01 is the name of Event collection that u will find in your Project.
key is the name of the value. 'data.nodes' is the value.